# Tele-zoom lens choices for Nikon 1 J1?

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, nikon-1

I recently got a Nikon 1 J1 camera and would like a bigger lens, I've been looking on the internet for answers but can't seem to find anything. I was looking for a 30-110mm size or larger at a reasonable price, i've tried the Nikon website but don't seem to be getting anywhere.

I mainly use it for wildlife photography so any suggestions that would be good for this type of photography would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The Nikon 1 system uses a new lens mount, so there are few lenses. As of 2015, The [70-300](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Nikon-Products/Product/Nikon1-Lenses/1-NIKKOR-VR-70-300-f%252F4.5-5.6.html) is the longest available. Of course, that's effectively about 189mm–810mm mm (in the 35 mm format), so that's a fairly long lens.

Another option is [Nikon's FT1](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Nikon-Products/Product/Lens-Adapters/3613/FT-1-Mount-Adapter.html) which will let you mount any of Nikon's F-mount lenses (AF-S lenses will be able to autofocus, you will need to focus manually with others) to your J1. Combine that with the AF-S NIKKOR 800mm and you've got some reach -- up to the equivalent of 2160mm! (Multiply by 2.7X)

Answer (score 2):

The Nikon 1 system uses its own, new lens mount. You can find a list at [Nikon's site](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Nikon-Products/Camera-Lenses/1-NIKKOR-Lenses/index.page). Or, retailer [B&H Photo has an easy search](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?atclk=Lens+Mount_Nikon+1&N=4196380428+4099560918) for lenses in this mount.

There is indeed a 30-110mm zoom lens, as well as a bigger, heavier, and more expensive 10-100mm. There aren't any other telephoto options for the system yet, so short of using an adapter those are basically your only options for wildlife.

Answer (score 1):

The 1 NIKKOR VR 30-110mm f/3.8-5.6 is shown on [Nikon's USA website](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Nikon-Products/Product/Nikon1-Lenses/3312/1-NIKKOR-VR-30-110mm-f%252F3.8-5.6.html) with a retail price of $249.95.

Several merchants sell it thorough [amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005NFW9PG) in white or black for $246.95.

While $250 is not exactly a trivial amount, it is on the lower end of the scale for detachable camera lenses.

Answer (score 1):

Since the posting of this question, Nikon has put out a new lens for the nikon 1 system: the 1 nikon 70-300 f/4.5-5.6. Due to the crop factor, this actually comes down to a massive 189-810mm focal distance. I don't have much experience with it, but from what little I used it, it is much lighter than most DSLR zoom lenses, but it suffers in low light conditions due to the camera itself and the wide minimal aperture.

I think that if you're accustomed to the 30-110mm in terms of light performance, you can expect the about the same with the 70-300. It will probably perform pretty well in good light conditions, but getting birds in flight might pose a problem.

Another concern might be the price point, currently, I'm looking at a €1000.- price tag which is over double the price I paid for a nikon 1 v1 with a 10-30mm kit lens. In the end it comes down to preference: if you have quite some nikon lenses laying around, the FT-1 adapter is a reasonable albeit pricey alternative. If you want to have a load of extra zoom, but still the same light performance and a pretty low weight for it's focal range, the 70-300mm is a reasonable choice